# Multiple SELECT statements are not work in the stored-procedures in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I've `stored-procedures` with `SELECT` three database columns but when I put it as one  `SELECT` it is not working by the way when it put as three different `SELECT` statements work it fine.

**Working query**

```
        BEGIN


            SET child = chid; 
            myloop: loop
            IF x = loop_val  THEN
                LEAVE myloop;
            END IF;      

            SELECT IFNULL(parent_pageid,0) into parent FROM page_content pc WHERE pc.pageid = child;
            SELECT sef_url into sef_string FROM page_content pc WHERE pc.pageid = child;         

            SELECT  menu_heading into menu_string FROM page_content pc WHERE pc.pageid = child;


        END
```

When `SELECT` as follows it is not working

```
SELECT IFNULL(parent_pageid,0) into parent, sef_url into sef_string, menu_heading into menu_string FROM page_content pc WHERE pc.pageid = child;
```

Is there any wrong with the single `SELECT` statements?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to list all selected columns then all variables, like this:

```
SELECT
    IFNULL(parent_pageid,0),
    sef_url,
    menu_heading
INTO
    parent,
    sef_string,
    menu_string 
FROM page_content pc 
WHERE pc.pageid = child;
```